# After clone find and adding a text gives wrong output

Tags: jquery

I am cloning a div, after i would like to find an element to update the text. I do like this:

```
constructRightNavi : function () {
            var cloneCategory = null;
            if(!this.sideBar.find('#'+this.category).length)
                cloneCategory = categoryHolder.clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .prop('id', this.category)
                                .find('.text')
                                .text(this.category);;

                this.sideBar.find('.queryWrapper').before(cloneCategory);
        }
```

But in the output, all are gone

I am getting the output as the last finded element alone like this:

```
<span class="text">Mechanical</span>
```

How to clone and update the element?

**Update:**

In case if I update like this, it works!

```
if(!requiredCategory.length) {
                this.clonedCategory = categoryHolder.clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .prop('id', this.category);
                this.clonedCategory.find('.text').text(this.category); //after clone finding works
                this.sideBar.find('.queryWrapper').before(this.clonedCategory);
            }
```

Comment: how about assigning `this` to a local variable? It might be having conflict.

Comment: In case if i remove `.find('.text').text(this.category);` all works fine. that's what i wondering with the issue.

Comment: That's why I'm saying that it might be having conflict with `this`. that `this` after `.find('.text')` might be the result of the `find()`, not the original `this`.

Comment: Can you add more detail to this question? Not enough information is given to be able to give an accurate answer.

Comment: @RichardRout - added working version with different approach in question update - have a look.